# Is it possible to have a Captive portal pop-up on android when reverse tethering?

Tags: reverse, tethering, captiveportal

I am trying to set up captive portal interfaces on my nvidia device. Right now I am currently using hostapd, dnsmasq and nginx to set up this process. I have already successfully gotten a captive portal to pop-up on a persons device when they are connecting to my nvidia device using a wireless access point and through ethernet.

My question is: is it possible to set up the same kind of architecture for a captive portal to pop-up when someone is connecting via USB. From my limited understanding on this it seems I would need to be reverse-tethering for this to happen, which I have implemented using gnirehtet. I am just curious if it is possible for a captive portal to pop-up on someone's device when connecting to mine via USB?

Any guidance would be great!